# How to see events in Remix - Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, events

I am new to solidity and trying to deploy a contract to see whether the address is EOA or Smart Contract. The code is listed below. I am not able to see the boolean value when I executed the contract in the mainnet.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Ballot {

event isEOAOrNot(bool val);

function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
  uint size;

  assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
  bool val = size > 0;
  isEOAOrNot(val);
  return val;
}




}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's the best way I know:

1. Launch contract:

[image: Step 1]

2. Run transaction:

[image: Step 2]

3. View transaction data:

[image]

4. Find the "event" and "args" parameters under logs:
   [image]

And there you have it; the event and the arguments.

Comment: It's not there.

Comment: @ErickRobertson if you could provide more details, I will try and see what went wrong. On what step did you get stuck?

Comment: It was there for me, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is pretty uncomfortable to have to extract the events from the details like this. Can't it be automated and the events printed below the transaction somehow? Is there a plugin that could do it?

Answer (score 3):

You've missed the emit when calling the isEOAOrNot(val) event.
should be:

```
emit isEOAOrNot(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you compile a different contract, previous contracts that you deployed will no longer show events.
So, recompile the contract you want to see the events for before calling the method.